# How can I save data from an EditText component so it shows up when the app is reopened?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I am using Android Studio and programming in Kotlin. I haven't been able to find a way to save the data entered by the user so it appears when they reopen the app. Thank you ahead of time!

Comment: you can store it in sharedpreferences

Comment: please show us your code what you have done so far and if there is an error when saving

Answer (score 0):

You have to store your data in shared preference when any click event listen or on edittext textwatcher you can set your character in preference but best way is on any click event save data on preference and when activity open set data from preference on edittext.

Answer (score 0):

Store it in Shared Preferences

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
```

use this save the value..

```
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("key_name", "value"); //here give name and value to save
editor.commit();
```

use this to get the value.

```
String edittextvalue = pref.getString("key_name", null); //put edittextvalue  where ever you what to show the value.
```

use this step to remove or clear the value

```
editor.remove("name");
editor.commit();
```